# how to plot dashed and smoothed error lines around a regression line in R

Tags: r, regression

This is my first time using stack overflow and so I hope I am able to articulate my question adequately. If more information is needed, please ask. Here we go:

I have used the `predict` function to return to me average weights and standard errors for varying levels of infection in fish.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
outp=predict(model1,newdata=table1,type="response",se.fit=T)

mean.response=as.data.frame(cbind(outp$fit,outp$se.fit))
```

Then a dataframe gets returned to me with the mean response for a certain level of infection  and the associated standard errors. I then calculated the standard error above the mean and below the mean for each infection level. I would like to plot the regression line through those means with the standard errors around it, but in the form of connected dashed lines instead of error bars. And instead of the means that determine the regression line being points along that line, it would be great if I could show them as ticks along the x-axis.

Please let me know if there is any more information that I could provide.

Thank you,
Paul

Comment: 4 spaces before a line makes it code on your post. (syntax highlight)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please show us the plot code you have tried, and explain why it didn't work. You are much more likely to receive a helpful answer if you provide a [minimal, reproducible data set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the code you have tried. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Henrick and Plasmarob. I will add a simple dataset tomorrow. I look forward to it. Thanks